# Allow for unquoted soap action JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

How can you relax the rules on request validation for a jax-ws web service? I need to be able to receive requests with unquoted soap actions and process them. Currently all that happens is the client recieves a 400 error and I get a warning (com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter fixQuotesAroundSoapAction Received WS-I BP non-conformant Unquoted SoapAction HTTP header)

I dont have any control over the incoming request and cannot force them to be conformant.

Here is the HTTP trace. I can post the wsdl if relevant.

```
POST /delivery HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.225)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: http://schemas.cjse.gov.uk/endpoint/wsdl/submit
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Length: 11918
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><NS2:SubmitRequestMes xmlns:NS2="http://schemas.cjse.gov.uk/endpoint/types/"><NS2:RequestID>leeflaxington_Z00CJSE_09251446338592</NS2:RequestID><NS2:SourceID>Z00CJSE</NS2:SourceID><NS2:DestinationID>00101PoliceCaseSystem</NS2:DestinationID><NS2:ExecMode>ASYNCH</NS2:ExecMode><NS2:Timestamp>2014-09-25T14:48:00.9375+01:00</NS2:Timestamp><NS2:Message>message data</NS2:Message></NS2:SubmitRequestMes></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Content-Length: 0

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Thu, 25 Sep 2014 14:03:37 GMT
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

1ce
<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns=""><faultcode>S:Server</faultcode><faultstring>javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[100,496]
Message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.]</faultstring></S:Fault></S:Body></S:Envelope>
0

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 40
Content-Type: text/html

<h1>400 Bad Request</h1>Bad request line
```

Comment: The error message says: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[100,496] Message: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity and not the warning you mention in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the command line error was a red herring. The issue was the post body had incorrect content length. This caused invalid xml envelope thus the soap error shown.

Comment: You saved my life, really. I had been getting the same error for almost two weeks before finally noticed that it was data problem few minutes ago.